# React.js create-react-app Npm Run Build - Failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

In my React create-react-app projects npm start is working fine, but the 'build' script fails almost immediately.

The error says failed to compile - 'EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read'

I've tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling node & npm using nvm.

I've tried creating a new create-react-app project without editing any of preloaded code, and build still fails.

terminal error message:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! personal-website@0.1.0 build: react-scripts build
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the personal-website@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/Stew/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/Stew/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2
3 info using node@v12.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle personal-website@0.1.0~prebuild: personal-website@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle personal-website@0.1.0~build: personal-website@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle personal-website@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle personal-website@0.1.0~build: PATH: /Users/Stew/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/Stew/Desktop/personal-website/node_modules/.bin:/Users/Stew/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle personal-website@0.1.0~build: CWD: /Users/Stew/Desktop/personal-website
10 silly lifecycle personal-website@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle personal-website@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle personal-website@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/Stew/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:326:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/Stew/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid personal-website@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/Stew/Desktop/personal-website
16 verbose Darwin 18.6.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/Stew/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/bin/node" "/Users/Stew/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.7.0
19 verbose npm  v6.10.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error personal-website@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the personal-website@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

package.json
{
  "name": "personal-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I expect the react project to successfully compile the production build script, but instead it creates the build repository and immediate fails after creating a manifest.json and gives the error message listed above.

Comment: I think this issue could help u => https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4336